# Is there a script to delete a row based on a particular cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to find a script for a button so that when I press it, if a certain cell contains any number that's less than 5, the row it's on is deleted. For instance, cell G13 is <5 so delete row.

I can't find anything online for this type of script - is this possible?

Comment: Definitely possible - do some research on `.getValues()` method, `if` statements & `.deleteRow()` method, should be easily achieveable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Small sample:**

Delete a row if a cell value is <5:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("G13");
  var cellContent = cell.getValue();
  if (cellContent < 5){
    var row = cell.getRow();
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

### UPDATE:

Delete all rows where  a cell value in a certain column is <5:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var columnG = sheet.getRange(1,7, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < columnG.length; i++){
    var cellContent = columnG[i][0];
    if (cellContent < 5){
      var row = i+1;
      sheet.deleteRow(row);
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend you to study the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to gain a deeper understanding.

Comment: That's great, I can see how that works now, thank you. Just one more thing - how do I get the script to check the whole column for numbers <5 and then delete those rows?

Comment: For this you need to retrieve the whole column and then iterate with an `for` loop through all cells and implement the `if` statement within the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply zignotschka. I think this is starting to go over my head a little now - I'll do some reading and research!

Comment: Thanks again! I don't know how to retrieve the whole column and use the for/if statements though, are you able to give me an example?

Comment: I updated my answer to give you a sample. However, it is crucial that you do a bit of reading to understand why the code works the way it does and how to modify it.